# socket.io react sets array to empty when mutating with useState() through a socket.io event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

I'm trying to move the orange square through a socket.io event "controller_input". The underlying data structure is an array composed with useState() hook. Whenever I send a move signal through that socket.io event, setState() hook makes the array empty, but moves the square one cell to the right and rest of my grid disappears. I'm very confused on what is happening here. Mutating state with on screen direction buttons work fine though.

```
//this is the array that renders the grid and gets set to 
//empty later on
const [propGrid, setPropGrid] = React.useState([]);

//setting up and registering events for socket.io
let socket = null;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //onMount
    console.log("--GAME UI on mount gets called");

    ref.current = handlePlayerMovement;

    if (socket == null) {
      socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, { transports: ["websocket"] });
    }

    //identify the client
    socket.emit("identification_message", {
      client_type: "game",
    });

    const callback = (message) => {
      console.log("callback gets called");
      handlePlayerMovement({ a: "b" }, message.message);
      console.log(propGrid);
    };

    socket.on("controller_input", callback);

    constructPropGrid();

    return () => {
      console.log("websocket unmounting!!!!!");
      socket.off("controller_input", callback);
    };
  }, []);
```

handlePlayerMovement() eventually calls a function likes this to mutate state

```
const mutateStateToMovePlayer = (curerentIndex, nextIndex) => {
    //extract currentIndex from player
    console.log("--mutateStateToMovePlayer, ", curerentIndex, nextIndex);

    //unmark current cell
    let board = [...propGrid];
    board[curerentIndex] = <GridSquare key={`${curerentIndex}`} color="" />;
    
   //get and set new index
    let newIndex = index;
    newIndex = nextIndex;
    setIndex(newIndex);
    
    //mark the new cell orange to signify the player has moved
    board[newIndex] = <GridSquare key={`${newIndex}`} color="1" />;
    setPropGrid(board);
  };
```

[image: initial grid]

[image: when I try to move down]

Comment: Which specific array/variable becomes empty and which setState is problematic? Could you please include your full component code and add more details?

Comment: A tip that'll make things easier to reason about: don't store JSX elements in state, instead store objects/arays/primitives in state and transform them into JSX only when it comes time to render

Comment: Yeah, I would not store jsx elements like that, if you need to update the background color, store the refs in an array and update their style

Comment: The funny thing is, whenever I try to update non JSX state variables through the socket.io event, it still gets reset to their original value. So I think this may not be exclusive to storing JSX in state.